# Which could be a possible time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

I have the following algorithmen (picture) which calculates a Vertex Cover and gets an undirected $G(V,E)$ Graph as input.

[image: Algorithm]

The following task is to find the possible Time complexity (estimate) while $n = |V|$, $m = |E|$,
$n \le m + 1$ and $deg(v) = |N(v)|$:

a) $O(n log n)$

b) $O(n + m)$

c) $O(2^n*m)$

d) $O(n^k*m)$

e) $|V| \choose k$ * $\sum_{v \in V} deg(v) $

---

Clearly a,b cannot be an estimate running time for the algorithm.

e) looks correct, but c and d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n=|V|$, and $\sum_{v\in V}deg(v) = 2\cdot |E| = 2m$ (each edge is counted exactly twice).

Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265519/approximation-of-combination-n-choose-k-theta-left-nk-right) for a proof why ${n \choose k} = \Theta(n^k)$ **for a fixed $k$**. Substitute everything, and get that also $O(n^k*m)$ is a valid estimate (again, only if $k$ is a fixed number!).

c) Is clearly not a tight bound, since it doesn't even depend on $k$ (although, this statement is by no means a proof).